# Linphone build error, Android L min target

Tags: android, ant, build, android-5.0-lollipop, linphone

I'm having problems compiling the linphone android project, i have read the instruction and installed the necessary packages to compile the project.

But at the I get this error at the end:

```
-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.1.0
[echo] Resolving Build Target for Linphone...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android L (Preview)
[gettarget] API level:        L

BUILD FAILED
/home/myHome/android-sdk/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:542: For 'L' SDK Preview, attribute      minSdkVersion in AndroidManifest.xml must be 'L' (current: 8)
```

I don`t  have too much experience with the ant build system. How can I change the project target of the build tools to sdk '19'?

Answer (score 0):

Change ANDROID_MOST_RECENT_TARGET=$(shell android list target -c | grep android | tail -n1) from Makefile in linphone project to ANDROID_MOST_RECENT_TARGET=android-17 or any android version

Answer (score -1):

under terminal :
   android update project -p  -t

targetSdkNo may not be 19 on your machine, to find it, type:
  android list targets
Then find the Index No for target 19.
On my machine, it is 1.
   so the command on my machine will be android update project -p "~/Work/prj1" -t 1